# Why is the community user making edits to content?

Tags: discussion, community

See [revision 2](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/7494/revisions) to my answer here.

The revision was done by the [community user](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), whose profile (ID = -1) says:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

If this is the case, then why did the community user change the text of the answer from "The Semichah that was given through the time of the Gemara" to "The Semichah that was given through the time of the <strike>Gemara</strike> Mishna" with the comment: "Rav Yehuda Hanasi (who wrote the mishna) was the last to have smicha. None of the Ravs in the Gemara had real smicha"? If someone wants to make an edit to actual content, it should be done in their own name!

Besides the fact that the correction is just wrong (see [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/hatkufa/mishpat-4.htm), paragraph that starts with "רבי מתווה להרבות בסמיכה" which gives sources as to how Rebbi told his son to give semicha to his students, and how Rebi Yehoshua ben Levi (a 3rd century Amora who lived long after Rebi) gave semicha to everyone in his yeshiva.

Answer (score 4):

This was a "suggested edit", proposed by an anonymous user.
(Unprivileged users can now make edits to content, but it doesnt happen right away: it goes into a queue and waits for a moderator or a high-privileged user to *approve* it. You'll see a number in the top bar when there are revisions awaiting approval...)
Since the user was anonymous (i.e. unregistered), it simply shows "Community", which is kind of the default user.
As for it being wrong - talk to @Isaac, [he's the one that approved it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/44). (In the revisions page you linked, notice on the relevant revision that it says "suggested 15 hours ago" (or whatever) - the `suggested` is a link - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/44 ).

Comment: Sorry. I did a little cursory research that indicated that the edit was correct, but was clearly too quick on the draw. Of course, the ultimate remedy is what @Yaakov did, which was to edit it back with listed justification.