# Update Community User Description

Tags: feature-request

See [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/why-is-the-community-user-making-edits-to-content) question for background.

I think that it is misleading that the community user is the user of record for approved community suggested errors - considering that the community user description does not mention that this is a function of the community user.

Suggestions (one or all)

1. Add to the description that community user is the user of record when community suggested edits for questions and answers are approved
2. In the mouse-over for community-suggested edits, give the name of the user who approved the edit

Alternatively, for community suggested edits that are approved, list the name of the approving user as the user of record for the update (after all, without their approval, it wouldn't go through) and add " (Community Edit)" after their name to indicate the source of the edit.

Answer (score 2):

I've [implemented](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) (1).